# In rxswift I can't send one parameter to CombineLatest. What should I use for one parameter?

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

In `rxswift` I can't send one parameter to `CombineLatest`. What should I use for one parameter?

```swift
import Foundation
import RxSwift

struct RegisterPhoneViewModel {

    var phoneNumberText = Variable<String>("")

    var isValid: Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(phoneNumberText.asObservable()) {phoneNum in
            phoneNum.count >= 11
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CombineLatest is for... combining things. Why would you want to combine just one thing, with nothing else? it's not combining anymore then. It looks like you might be looking for `map`

Comment: Also you should not use Variable, use BehaviorSubject instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the ‍`map` like this

```swift
import Foundation
import RxSwift

struct RegisterPhoneViewModel {

    var phoneNumberText = Variable<String>("")


    var isValid: Observable<Bool> {
        return self.phoneNumberText.asObservable().map {phoneNum  in
            phoneNum.count >= 11
        }
    }

}
```